# Javascript access array within object

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have a javascript object called event which is output from the console.log below:

```
{
"title": "Test Title",
"location": "Test Location",
"isAllday": false,
"isPrivate": false,
"state": "Busy",
"start": {
    "tzOffset": null,
    "d": {
        "d": "2023-01-03T16:00:00.000Z"
    }
},
"end": {
    "tzOffset": null,
    "d": {
        "d": "2023-01-03T16:30:00.000Z"
    }
},
"id": "afdb82fd-fddd-58ce-bd0b-ab0beb2bce7b"
```

}

I can access some items through `alert(event['title'] + event['location']);`
I cannot access the nested items like `start.tzOffset.d`
If I try `alert(event['title'] + event['start']['tzOffset']['d']);` I get an error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'd')"

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: You’re trying to access 'd' IN 'tzOffset' - but it's not there, but in other d. I mean event['start']['d']['d'].

Comment: Voted to close as this is equivalent to a typo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because `tzOffset` doesn't have a nested key called `d` inside of it.
instead it is inside `start` object and inside `d` object there is a key called `d` so it needs to be like this:

```
alert(event['title'] + event['start']['d']['d']);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can access the `d` from `event['start']['d']['d'])`, Because tzOffset doesn't have any value to access.

Answer (score -1):

```
alert(event['title'] + event['start']['d'])
```

It seems that there is no key "d" in "tzOffset",because it is null.

Comment: [A code-only answer is not high quality](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/392712/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers). While this code may be useful, you can improve it by saying why it works, how it works, when it should be used, and what its limitations are. Please [edit] your answer to include explanation and link to relevant documentation.